# Updating List<> used in xaml and reload frame

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, uwp

So i have an XML file that i load data into a List<> from.
That means that i have a main list that contains all the data i need.

From that list i the create variable "sub" lists that i then will use to present data, as needed.

My main window (as for now) contains a frame that i use to load in pages.

My problem is, that i can't figure out how you change the data to be shown on a page, reload it and keep it from showing the standard data.

So i think there a two ways of attacking this, but i need advise on what is the right(working) way.

So on my page1 (loaded into the frame) i have the following code:

```
public sealed partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public List<Book> Books;
    public List<Book> ts1;

    public Page1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Books = BookManager.GetBooks();
        ts1 = Books.Where(p => p.bogNa == "Robert").ToList();
    }

    private void Update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ts1 = Books.Where(p => p.bogNa != "Robert").ToList();

    }
}
```

So i can with my button update the list, but obviously when i then reload the frame, we are just back to square one. Can i do it different from the page?

In my page1 xaml i have this code:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ts1}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Book">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid Height="200">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Row="0" Name="pic" Width="150" Source="{x:Bind bogCo }"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" FontSize ="20" Text="{x:Bind bogNa}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" FontSize ="16" Text="{x:Bind bogRe}"/>
                        <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="More Info" FontSize="16">
                            <Button.Flyout>
                                <Flyout x:Name="FlyoutTest">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind bogAr}">

                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Flyout>
                            </Button.Flyout>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Is there a way to change

```
<GridView ItemSource="{x:bind ts1}" ...
```

To a different page than page1, like the MainPage?

Iv'e looked into making a **data template** but i don't know is that is the way to go? because i don't want to spend my time on that, for now, if it leads to the same problems.

Comment: Take a look at MVVM, by keeping the VIewModel you keep the user changes.

Comment: Do you know any places where i can find education on this? Every time i look its all the pre x:bind version tutorials i find. I am having a really hard time finding anything on UWP really..

Comment: This looks nice:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a good solution: ObservableCollection

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public List<dataRaw> t1;
        public List<dataRaw> t3;
        public ObservableCollection<dataRaw> t2;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            //So you call the information from a class file (normally in Models)
            t1 = collectionGenerator.getList();
            //Then you use the t1 (List<T>) and convert it to an ObservableCollection
            t2 = new ObservableCollection<dataRaw>(t1);
        }

        private void Filter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Gather user input from a textbox (TB1)
            // clear the data in ObservableCollection t2
            t1 = collectionGenerator.getList();
            t2.Clear();
            string data = TB1.Text;

            //Check what input the user have entered
            if(data != "")
            {
            var Vtest = from VT in t1
                        where VT.firstName == data || VT.lastName == data
                        select VT;
                foreach (var VT in Vtest)
                {
                    //Add the given data back to the t2
                    t2.Add(new dataRaw { data = "1", firstName = VT.firstName, lastName = VT.lastName });

                }
            }
            else
            {
                var Vtest = from VT in t1
                            where VT.data == "1"
                            select VT;
                foreach (var VT in Vtest)
                {
                    t2.Add(new dataRaw { data = "1", firstName = VT.firstName, lastName = VT.lastName });

                }
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to solve this problem would be to enable the `NavigationCacheMode` for Page1.

This caches the state of page1 and shows the old state when reopening the page.
Just remember that you cannot empty the cache once the page is initialized. Also the `NavigationCacheMode` must be set in the constructor of the page.

```
public Page1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled; // or NavigationCacheMode.Required if you want to ignore caching limits.
    Books = BookManager.GetBooks();
    ts1 = Books.Where(p => p.bogNa == "Robert").ToList();
}
```

But like Inbar Barkai said, a cleaner solution would be to keep the ViewModel of page1.